# Why is the ClientID different on PreInit than in Init or PreRender?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

A little background... at work I was upgraded to Windows 7 (64-bit) from Windows XP (32-bit). While upgrading, I was also switched from:

- Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition to Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web
- ASP.Net 2.0 to ASP.Net 4.5.1
- Subversion to GitHub

I'm in the process of testing my website to make sure nothing broke, and something did... storing values in `ViewState` by a key I specify seems to have broken.

Early on, I created a few user controls (.ascx) to make life a little easier. In order to persist properties, I stored them in `ViewState` which worked absolutely fine in ASP.Net 2.0.

Example of property storage (from my `ValidatedTextBox` class, which is an `<asp:TextBox />` with a predefined validators):

```
Private ReadOnly Property ViewStateControlPrefix() As String
    Get
        Return "Maggie:ValidatedTextBox:" & txt.ClientID & ":"
    End Get
End Property

Public Property TextMode() As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode
    Get
        If Not ViewState(Me.ViewStateControlPrefix & "TextMode") Is Nothing Then
            Return ViewState(Me.ViewStateControlPrefix & "TextMode")
        Else
            Return System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode.SingleLine
        End If
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode)
        ViewState(Me.ViewStateControlPrefix & "TextMode") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now that the update to ASP.Net 4.5.1 has occurred, this no longer works as I intended.

The `ViewStateControlPrefix` returns what I expect (e.g., `"Maggie:ValidatedTextBox:ctl00_cphMaggie_vtKeywords_txt:"`), but that is not what the key in the ViewState actually is (and it should be).

Here's a screenshot of what's happening in the debugger:

[image: Weird Keys that I didn't set in ViewState]

The difference in the keys boils down to the `ClientID` property.

In the `Get`, it's set to `ctl00_cphMaggie_vtResponse_txt` but in the `Set` it's set to `vtResponse_txt` which puts me at a loss when I want to retrieve the value.

The `pages` element in `web.config` had `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"` and `clientIDMode="AutoID"` added to it automatically, and I suspect the `clientIDMode` has to do with my problem (although I've tried switching it to `Predictable` with no effect). I've also tried using `UniqueID`, but the same problem occurs (`ctl00$cphMaggie$vtResponse$txt` to `vtResponse$txt` respectively).

I assume that `Set` is called on `PreInit` as I set the properties via the markup in the ascx:

```
<Maggie:ValidatedTextBox ID="vtResponse" runat="server" CSSClass="rte" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="60" Rows="20" IsRequiredField="false" IsValidatedField="false" ScrubberFunction="trim(normalizeWhitespace(this));" ScrubberFunctionTrigger="onchange" />
```

And the `Get` is explicitly called on `PreRender`.

Can someone please enlighten me as to:

- Why this worked in ASP.Net 2.0, but not now?
- What's causing this?
- How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Switching the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` makes the `ClientID` property very consistent (although not unique enough when multiple `ValidatedTextBox` controls are on the same page).

I also added this to the control's code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Dim clientId As String = txt.ClientID
    Dim uniqueId As String = txt.UniqueID
    Dim h As Hashtable = New System.Collections.Hashtable(ViewState)
    Dim i As Integer = 0 'Used for a breakpoint
End Sub
```

After pausing on the `Dim i As Integer` line, it's clear that by the time the `Init` event is firing, the `ClientID` property is set (and in the manner I'm used to).

Also, there does not appear to be a `PreInit` event to capture in the .ascx.vb code-behind (I get `"Event 'PreInit' cannot be found"`), so now I'm really curious as to when the property setters are called.

**UPDATE**

I've tried all of the following:

1. Changed the `ViewStateControlPrefix` to `Return "Maggie:ValidatedTextBox:" & txt.UniqueID & ":"`
2. Added `clientIDMode` to the `<%@ Control %>` block in the .ascx.
3. Added `clientIDMode` to the `<asp:Textbox />` in the .ascx.
4. Cycled through `AutoID`, `Predictable`, `Inherit`, and `Static` in the `pages` element.
5. Cycled through `AutoID`, `Predictable`, `Inherit`, and `Static` in the `<%@ Control %>` block in the .ascx.
6. Cycled through `AutoID`, `Predictable`, `Inherit`, and `Static` in  the `<asp:Textbox />` in the .ascx.
7. Changed the `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` from `3.5` to `4.0` to `4.5`.
8. Removed both `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` and `clientIDMode` from the `pages` element in `web.config`
9. Googled feverishly (again) for a solution with no success.
10. Googled instead to determine when the `ClientID` property is set in the ASP.Net Page Life Cycle (with no success, either).

It doesn't seem to matter what I change. The `ViewStateControlPrefix` getter is returning `vtResponse_txt` when called from a setter and something else (depending on what I've changed) when called from a getter.

Does anyone have any idea why this behavior is so radically different from ASP.Net 2.0? Or how to change it back?

Comment: Its been a while, but a similar issue of the apparent stripping of "ctl00_cphMaggie_" seemed to occur when the child control was not properly reconciled in the parents control collection.

Comment: @brumScouse: Any idea how to tell if that's the case, or how to properly reconcile the child control in the parent's collection?

Comment: My memory is vague and I cant remember whether this involved dynamically adding controls,are your controls added at design time or dynamically?. If so, the point at which these badgers are being loaded would almost definitely be causing an issue.

Comment: @brumScouse: They're added declaratively, not dynamically.

Comment: And here is where I bow out, sorry couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I have come up with was to re-write the `ViewStateControlPrefix` getter to return a unique value independent of `ClientIDMode` settings:

```
Private ReadOnly Property ViewStateControlPrefix() As String
    Get
        Dim parts As String() = Me.ClientID.Split("_")
        Dim id As String = Me.ClientID 'Default to ClientID
        Dim prefix As String = String.Empty

        If parts.Length > 0 Then
            'By using Me.ClientID, the last element of the array will always be
            'the ID specified in the markup, regardless of ClientIDMode settings.
            id = parts(parts.GetUpperBound(0))
        End If

        prefix = "Maggie:ValidatedTextBox:" & id & ":"

        Return prefix
    End Get
End Property
```

This returns a consistent value to use as a key in the `ViewState` bag, regardless of when this getter is called and regardless of `ClientIDMode` settings (where ever they may be set).

I'll leave this answer unaccepted for a while in case

- anyone can come up with a better solution
- or anyone can explain any of my original questions in the post:

  - Why this worked in ASP.Net 2.0, but not now?
  - What's causing this?
  - How can I fix it?
  - When in the Page LifeCycle the property setters are called when the properties are set declaratively?
  - why this behavior is so radically different from ASP.Net 2.0?
  - how to change it back?